# Java - Open questions to the Keyword "return"

Tags: java, class, methods, return, overriding

I have a question to the keyword "return" in java.

In the method called "change" a new person Object with the given argument n will be returned, but the defined object "pone" in the main will not be overridden with the new object. What happens to the "return new Person(n)" object after excuiting in the main method? A student told me that the "return new Person(n) will override the values in the pone object.

This the code:

```
public class Person {

    String name;

    Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    Person change(String n) {
        return new Person(n);
    }

    void setname(String n) {
        name = n;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person pone = new Person("Jack");
        System.out.println(pone.change("Julia"));
        System.out.println(pone);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
   System.out.println(pone.change("Julia")); -> Julia
   System.out.println(pone);  -> Jack
```

Comment: What you were told is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your student is incorrect.

`return new Person(n);` calls `Person(String name)`. There is nothing there that modifies the instance referred to by `this` at the calling site.

A more appropriate implementation of `change` is probably

```
Person change(String n) {
    name = n;
    return this;
}
```

assuming you wanted to still return a `Person` instance - more often than not such methods are a `void` type, but the way you have it does allow for *method chaining*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String change(String n) {
    return name = n;
}
```

Comment: There is already a method set that changes the value of name."void setName(String n)"

Comment: @Stultuske It will return String name only.

Answer (score 0):

I did not clearly understand what you say but if you want to change Jack to Julia you should do:

```
Person pone = new Person("Jack");
pone = pone.change("Julia");
```

Answer (score 0):

The keyword new here means that the change method will create a new instance of Person and that new instance is allocated its own memory, the this in the constructor then points to this new object which has been created. The object will not affect the existing person.

Comment: Will the new instance of Person be destroyed after excuting the method?

Comment: Well it depends:

if you never store or use that instance again then yes the GC will come along and reclaim the memory. however if you store the output of the change method into a new person then no it will still be available to use.

Answer (score 0):

Your student is incorrect. No values are getting overriden. Instead of one person object there are 2 person objects created.

Over here 2 Person objects are created. One has reference variable called "pone" (with value Jack)and the other one (with value Julia) does not have any reference variable to hold the object returned from "*change*" method.

1. System.out.println(pone.change("Julia")); prints Julia as the second object has 
   Julia as name. This value is not assigned to any reference variable so this 
   value can never be accessed in future and would be eligible for GC.
2. System.out.println(pone); prints Jack as pone is the reference variable which 
   holds the value of the first person object.